# Displaying a sum incrementally per row using window function in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I need to enter the total length of `verblijfsduur` (stay) per `reisnr` (trip) incrementally according to the order in which the celestial objects are visited.

**This what I need:** (ignore the tot_duur column, that is the sum of all verblijfsduur)

[image]

**This what I get**, see it dosn't show incrementally according to order, it shows the total per`reisnr` (trip number):

[image]

I don't know how I could indicate this in the `PARTITION BY` part of my query:

```
SELECT re.reisnr, be.volgnr, be.objectnaam, be.verblijfsduur
,sum(be.verblijfsduur) OVER (PARTITION BY re.reisnr ORDER BY re.reisnr ) as 
inc_duur
FROM reizen re INNER JOIN bezoeken be ON re.reisnr = be.reisnr
ORDER BY re.reisnr, be.volgnr, be.objectnaam, be.verblijfsduur
```

Comment: Edit your question and put the code in the question as text, not an image.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, thanks/sorry if you had an answer, I had to order by `be.volgnr`

```
SELECT re.reisnr, be.volgnr, be.objectnaam, be.verblijfsduur
,SUM(be.verblijfsduur) OVER (PARTITION BY re.reisnr ORDER BY be.volgnr) as inc_duur

FROM reizen re INNER JOIN bezoeken be ON re.reisnr = be.reisnr
ORDER BY re.reisnr, be.volgnr, be.objectnaam, be.verblijfsduur
```